# Given a json object want to filter out multiple specific fields

Tags: java, json, string, object

```
 {
    "hits":[
      {
      date: "10142201"
      name: "jeremy"
      age:"19"
      identity:"A"
     },
      {
      date:"10142202"
      name: "zach"
      age: "20"
      identity:"B"
     },
      {
      date:"10142203"
      name: "Jack"
      age: "21"
      identity:"C"
     },
      {
      date:"10142204"
      name: "Jimmy"
      age:"23"
      identity:"D"
     }
    ],
    total: "4",
    name: "generic-names"
    identity: "generic-identity"
    }
```

Given this JSON object I would want to filter out specific fields. So if I wanted title and total I would want it to be returned as an JSON object like this:

```
 {
    "hits":[
      {
      name: "jeremy"
     },
      {
      name: "zach"
     },
      {
      name: "Jack"
     },
      {
      name: "Jimmy"
     }
    ],
    total: "4",
    }
```

- Right now I am only able to get one field at a time with the get parameter but I would want it to be outputted as JSON object how it is above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your JSON sample is not a valid JSON. Those keys need to be enclosed by double quote ".

For your requirement, you need to build a new JSON from the source data. Or you can use any JSON query language library to do that.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString("{\n" +
    "    \"hits\": [\n" +
    "        {\n" +
    "            \"date\": \"10142201\",\n" +
    "            \"name\": \"jeremy\",\n" +
    "            \"age\": \"19\",\n" +
    "            \"identiry\": \"A\"\n" +
    "        },\n" +
    "        {\n" +
    "            \"date\": \"10142202\",\n" +
    "            \"name\": \"zach\",\n" +
    "            \"age\": \"20\",\n" +
    "            \"identiry\": \"B\"\n" +
    "        },\n" +
    "        {\n" +
    "            \"date\": \"10142203\",\n" +
    "            \"name\": \"Jack\",\n" +
    "            \"age\": \"21\",\n" +
    "            \"identiry\": \"C\"\n" +
    "        },\n" +
    "        {\n" +
    "            \"date\": \"10142204\",\n" +
    "            \"name\": \"Jimmy\",\n" +
    "            \"age\": \"23\",\n" +
    "            \"identiry\": \"D\"\n" +
    "        }\n" +
    "    ],\n" +
    "    \"total\": \"4\",\n" +
    "    \"name\": \"generic-names\",\n" +
    "    \"identiry\": \"generic-identity\"\n" +
    "}");
    JsonNode node = josson.getNode("map(hits.map(name), total)");
    System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "hits" : [ {
    "name" : "jeremy"
  }, {
    "name" : "zach"
  }, {
    "name" : "Jack"
  }, {
    "name" : "Jimmy"
  } ],
  "total" : "4"
}
```